# noMethodError in form.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I want to post a new status, I have the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Statuses#new
Showing C:/Users/NEBELYN/Desktop/mybook/mybook/app/views/statuses/_form.html.erb where        #16 raised:

undefined method `name' for #<Status:0x4f11510>
Extracted source (around line #16):
13
14  <div class="field">
15       <%= f.label :name %><br>
16      <%= f.text_field :name %>
17    </div>
18    <div class="field">
19     <%= f.label :content %><br>
```

Comment: do you have a column or a method `name` associated to the model `Status`?

Comment: column, i created a table of statuses, with columns name:string and content:text, i deleted the name, because i want to replace the name with the users name he loged into the app with

Comment: i found the error, thanks